# Sed: get the first part of a line till "_Sxx_" where xx is 0-999

Tags: bash, file, sed, grep, line

I have a lot of files (~9000) they are named like this:

```
Something_some_more_even_more_S0_other_stuff    
Something_S2_other_stuff    
Something_even_more_S13_other_stuff
Something_some_more_even_S999_other_stuff
```

As you see the length of the bit in front of the delimiter Sxx is not fixed.
Also the delimiter can range from `S0` to `S999` (not `S01` or so).
The underscores are actually there.

So how to get the first part till `Sxx`?

Comment: So if it has two S numbers on a line get up to the first one ?

Comment: There is only one such number in the line :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/_S[0-9]\+_.*$//' file
Something_some_more_even_more
Something
Something_even_more
Something_some_more_even
```

In this `sed` command we match using pattern starting from `_S<digit>` and ending at line end i.e. `$`. In replacement we just use an empty string.

This awk will also work:

```
awk -F '_S[0-9]+_.*$' '{print $1}' file
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, i did not down vote, your solution works but the _Sxx is still there it would be better if the get removed also. Also could you explain the regexp to me ?

Comment: Note that the `+` is not a metacharacter in POSIX `sed`.  GNU `sed` seems to more or less support it out of the box; Mac OS X (BSD) `sed` can be persuaded to recognize `+` (without a backslash) as a metacharacter if you use `-E`.